# Django and jython-standalone

Tags: python, jython, psql, psycopg

I am pretty new to Django and Jython. I am trying  to create war file which can be deployed to Jboss server. Unfortunately I have a problem with psycopg2 library.

I am using  the modjy servlet so my library are placed in lib-python folder under WEB-INFO (it contains both Djongo and psycopg2 as well as others).

Application deploys to Jboss without any problem. Unfortunately when I am trying to access any page I could see following problem:

modjy.modjy_exceptions.ApplicationException: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named _psycopg

Does anybody have any idea why? psycopg2 folder contains _psycopg.so file which is accessible by everybody.

Comment: I think the problem is that psycopg2 is a C extension, and therefore incompatible with Jython. See  http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just founded that http://jyni.org/